# Flatten an object into object.name , object.value in Mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a record in collection like this. In cities, the name of the key or values are not constant

```
[
{
        "id" : "xxx",
        "countryName" : "xxx",
        "cities" : {
            "melbourne" : {
                "id" : "xxx",
                "cityName" : "xxx",
                "population" : 124
            },
            "brisbane" : {
                "column1" : "xxx",
                "column2" : "xxx"
            }
            .....
        }
    }
]
```

I need a response like

```
{
cities.melbourne : {"id" : "xxx", "cityName" : "xxx", "population" : 124 },
cities.brisbane : { "column1" : "xxx", "column2" : "xxx" },
......}
```

Comment: `cities` is an object, right! Since its an object you can easily use dot annotation as you mentioned. You don't need to flat the object.

Comment: Why would you want object keys to have `dot(.)` like that. As mentioned above, you already have the data in accessible format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": { //Converting cities to array
      "cities": {
        "$objectToArray": "$cities"
      }
    }
  },
  { //Flattening
    "$unwind": "$cities"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": { //Reshaping to the desired structure
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            {
              "k": {
                "$concat": [
                  "cities",
                  ".",
                  "$cities.k"
                ]
              },
              "v": "$cities.v"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_RC-0Hs-V88)

Output:

```
[
  {
    "cities.melbourne": {
      "cityName": "xxx",
      "id": "xxx",
      "population": 124
    }
  },
  {
    "cities.brisbane": {
      "column1": "xxx",
      "column2": "xxx"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected output using the aggregation operators `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` to transformation the input document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
    $addFields: { cities: { $objectToArray: "$cities" } } 
  },
  { 
    $unwind: "$cities" 
  },
  { 
    $addFields: { "cities.k": { $concat: [ "cities", ".", "$cities.k" ] } } 
  },
  { 
    $group: { _id: "$_id", cities: { $push: "$cities" } } 
  },
  { 
    $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: "$cities" }  
  }
])
```